# Custom Icons per Channel Entry on Google Map

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I am using Google Maps for EE in a site that shows rental properties. On each property's listing page (the page that shows one specific property), the client would like to have a Google Map that shows all properties but highlight the one the customer is viewing. They would also like to have their office populated on the map and have a unique icon for that marker.

So, each property will have a map with 60 pins but two of those need to be custom icons. The others can be the default Google Map icons.

Does this add-on allow that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In your channel entries tag where you output map markers you could add a conditional and add a class to the icon container.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Bluedreamer. To get the desired result I ended up having to not use the module and go with plain vanilla Google Maps code. I created a Stash variable using the channel entries tag to create an array, then added that Stash variable to the GM code.